# SPUser field is returning only ID in REST

Tags: 2013, jquery, rest, spuser

I have my multi-value SPUser field in my list. When accessing it via REST, I am only able to retrieve the ID of the SPUsers. In the result of the REST, the SPUser field was also appended by an Id in the column name. I would need to retrieve the Names of the user, what would be the easiest and most practical way to do it?

[image]

Comment: I am waiting to hear from you. Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the way SharePoint works. For lookup column it returns the Id only. If you need more information from lookup column, then just use `$expand` in your query. For example

```
/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('SpTutorial')/Items?$select=SPUser/Title&$expand=SPUser
```

Result without `$expand`

```
"SpUsersId": {
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "Collection(Edm.Int32)"
    },
    "results": [
      33,
      22
    ]
  }
```

Result with `$expand`

```
"SpUsers": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "e9a1d4f9-5d6d-4a4c-8753-ce1b5020b125",
          "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
        },
        "Title": "Mohammad Mazumder"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "6d968e6a-830a-4997-bba3-035dc1acdc85",
          "type": "SP.Data.UserInfoItem"
        },
        "Title": "Admin"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Check more about REST API in my article.

[CRUD Operation to List Using SharePoint 2013 Rest API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990131/CRUD-Operation-to-List-Using-SharePoint-Rest-API)

Comment: Hi Atish, I am not sure why it is not working while I was trying with my SPUser field. I am getting "The $expand query is not valid for field 'HOD'" Here is my query "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems?$select=HOD/Title&$expand=HOD" Any thoughts? I have both internal name and display name of my field as "HOD"

Comment: Url should be `"/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/Items?$select=HOD/Title&$expand=HOD"`. use `Item` instead of `getitems`.

Comment: Got it working now. I changed the way I call the rest. Thanks a lot!